# Change behaviour start menu shutdown button

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

I would like to change the behaviour of the "shutdown" and/or "restart" button in the start menu (I'm using windows 10).
I've already found that I can remove those buttons editing some options in gpedit.msc
But i would prefer to make the "shutdown" button do some action rather then remove it.
In particular it would be great if I could set as the shutdown event, to "disable screen" or if not possible to "change user".

Comment: You can't do this without third-party software.  Please note, with the use of third-party software, you might also lose the ability to do certain things with a group policy.

Answer (score 1):

You might find third-party tools such as Classic Shell *much* more versatile. For example, for dual-booting, I've added an option to delete *hiberfil.sys*. This is an image of options shown on clicking the *Shut Down* button on my PC:

[image: Image of my shutdown options]

Another way to customize shutdown is to write a small batch script, e.g.

> powercfg -h off
>
> shutdown /s /t 0

Make a shortcut to the script and put it in the *Start Menu*. You may need to set the shortcut's properties to run as Administrator.